# UnboundLocalError:local variabel 'socialhandle' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a django project and i'm trying to fetch data from the database, according to some primary key value. However when the object exists in the DB then everything is working fine but when it doesn't then django is raising:

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'socialhandle' referenced before assignment.

Here is my django view:

```
def profile(request, profile_id):
    """View for returning a unique profile"""
    profile = get_object_or_404(UserProfile, pk=profile_id)   

    try:
        socialhandle = SocialPlatform.objects.get(user_id=profile_id)
    except socialhandle.DoesNotExist:
        socialhandle = None

    context = {
        'profile' : profile,
        'socialhandle' : socialhandle,
    }

    return render(request, 'profiles/profile.html', context)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot access `socialhandle.DoesNotExist` in the except block because if the `try` does not interpret successfully, `socialhandle` would still be undefined.

Solution 1: Use Django's standard exception for this case:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist

...

try:
    socialhandle = SocialPlatform.objects.get(user_id=profile_id)
except ObjectDoesNotExist:
    socialhandle = None
```

Solution 2: Look at the answer of @JPG

Answer (score 2):

The ***proper*** way of handling the **`DoesNotExist`** is,

```
try:
    ...
except SomeModel.DoesNotExist:
    ...
```

Where the **`SomeModel`** should be the ***model class***, not the ***model "instance"***

---

So,
use **`except SocialPlatform.DoesNotExist`** instead of `except socialhandle.DoesNotExist`

```
def profile(request, profile_id):
    """View for returning a unique profile"""
    profile = get_object_or_404(UserProfile, pk=profile_id)   

    try:
        socialhandle = SocialPlatform.objects.get(user_id=profile_id)
    except SocialPlatform.DoesNotExist:
        socialhandle = None

    context = {
        'profile' : profile,
        'socialhandle' : socialhandle,
    }

    return render(request, 'profiles/profile.html', context)
```

Comment: I would go with this solution because less dependencies.